# Sample dBase files

Tags: file, sample, dbase

I am working on a program that will need to read different dBase files. I can only seem to find dBaseIII plus files for testing. Does anyone know where I can find a test pack or something? I need to test this code on different versions of dBase.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've cobbled together a collection of dBase files representing most versions for testing my own software.

You can find them all here:

https://github.com/infused/dbf/tree/master/spec/fixtures

The files are all named with the dBase version code (you can find the version code descriptions [here](https://github.com/infused/dbf/blob/master/lib/dbf/table.rb)):

```
dbase_03.dbf        dBase III without memo file
dbase_30.dbf        Visual FoxPro
dbase_31.dbf        Visual FoxPro with AutoIncrement field
dbase_83.dbf        dBase III with memo file
dbase_8b.dbf        dBase IV with memo file
dbase_f5.dbf        FoxPro with memo file
```

Those 6 account for most of the files I've seen in the wild.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good test file for dBase V.